# Cannot get proper Android O mediastyle notification

Tags: java, android, notifications

I'm out of options with Mediastyle Notification.

Here is the code as part of a MediaBrowserServiceCompat :

```
    private void showPlayingNotification() {

    Context context = MyApplication.getInstance().getApplicationContext();

    Intent resumeIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingResumeIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 12345, resumeIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);

    mBuilder.addAction(R.drawable.ic_back30, "rw30", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_REWIND))
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_player_pause, "Pause", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE))
            .addAction(R.drawable.ic_forward30, "ff30", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_FAST_FORWARD))
            .addAction(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_close_clear_cancel, "Stop", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_STOP))
    
            .setStyle(new Notification.MediaStyle()
                    .setShowActionsInCompactView(0,1,2)
                    .setMediaSession((MediaSession.Token) mMediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken().getToken()))

            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_rss_icon)
            .setLargeIcon(mMediaSessionCompat.getController().getMetadata().getDescription().getIconBitmap())
            .setContentIntent(pendingResumeIntent);
    
    startForeground(12345, mBuilder.build());
}
```

and here is what I get :
[notification with mediasession](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XI4uj.png)

I get the progress bar in the full size notification, but there are 2 issues :

- I don't get the app icon in the top bar
- I don't get the android O notification

So, when I comment out

```
.setMediaSession((MediaSession.Token) mMediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken().getToken()))
```

Here is what I get :
[notification without media session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1WCd6.png)

Now I get the app icon in the top bar, but 2 other problems remain :

- I don't get the progress bar in the full size notification
- No matter what I do with .setColorized() or .setColor(), the background remains white.

I'm doing this on a Samsung A52, Android 11.
Here is the gradle file :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application' 
android {
        compileSdkVersion 30

        defaultConfig {
                applicationId "com.podplay"
                minSdkVersion 30
                targetSdkVersion 30
                versionCode 1
                versionName "1.0"

                testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
            }

        buildTypes {
                release {
                    minifyEnabled false
                    proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
                }
            }
        }
```

last :

- no difference if I use Notification or NotificationCompat
- no additionnal setting in the builder seems to make a difference (priority, category, ...)
- I have tried with a 'this' as Context (instead of application), to no avail.

Thanks for any clue ...

Answer (score 1):

This is how the api works,
You have to either choose between the two
or create a custom mediastyle like this

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder()
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_player)
     .setLargeIcon(albumArtBitmap))
     .setCustomContentView(contentView);
     .setStyle(new Notification.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle()
          .setMediaSession(mySession))
     .build();
```

Check out: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but as DecoratedMediaCustomViewStyle is a subclass of MediaStyle, I don't get the application icon in the top bar, which is a concern ...